# Sum in TextBox with decimals

Tags: excel, vba

I have a listbox1 that counts prices in € with decimals. The sum of the prices is the value in my TextBox1.

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
   Me.ListBox1.AddItem .Range("B2").Value
   Me.ListBox1.Column(1, ListBox1.ListCount - 1) = Format(Val(.Range("C2").Value), "€#,##0.00")
   Me.TextBox1.Value = CDbl(Me.TextBox1.Value) + .Range("C2").Value
   Me.TextBox1.Value = Format(Me.TextBox1.Value, "#,##0.00")
End With
```

When I have a sum like 1.60 + 1.60 my value in the textbox is 32,00. I expect that the output is like 3.20.

Comment: You specify the format with this line "Me.TextBox1.Value = Format(Me.TextBox1.Value, "#,##0.00")" so change it...

Answer (score 2):

The decimal symbol in VBA depends on the regional settings of the PC. If it is dot, then it would be a dot in the code. Here is where to change it - search "Customize Format" in windows and change the "Decimal Symbol":

[image]

As an "ugly" workaround, try the `Replace()` formula:

```
Sub TestMe()
    MsgBox (Format(32, "#,##0.00"))
    MsgBox (Replace(Format(32, "##0.00"), ",", "."))
End Sub
```

It is "ugly", because the number would be treated as a `String` and not as a number any more. But it is ok if it is only to be displayed. Consider the thousand separator as well.